# How to get a form using its Id to pass to the submit function in js?

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of JS code as below:

> ```
> $('#modal-confirm').click(function(){
>         var myForm = $('#myForm');
>         model.saveForm(myForm);
>     });
> ```

the model.saveForm function is inside the view model object (knockoutjs)as below:

> ```
> self.saveBasicFormData = function(forms){
>     if(forms.length>0 && forms.id == 'myForm'){
>         var url = //url
>         $.post(url,$('#myForm').serialize());
>     }
> }
> ```

but when I confirm the modal, the 'if(forms.length>0 && forms.id == 'myForm')' inside the save function does not pass so that I can save the form. Actually the myForm variable is an object and I think I need to modify that var. but I do not know how.  Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a jQuery object - so your `forms` argument needs to be treated like a jQuery object (an array-like object) - your actual form DOM element will be at index `0`:

```
if(forms.length > 0 && forms[0].id == 'myForm'){ 
    ...
    $.post(url, $(forms[0]).serialize());
}
```

And you can make your code a little better - letting the form submit itself (eg. the url, method, etc is defined on the form):

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/url/to/form/processor">...</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', viewModel.saveMyForm);

// In your knockout code
self.saveMyForm = function(ev){
    var form = ev.target;
    ev.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting

    // do validation / clean data / etc

    form.submit(); // now we can submit the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is no attribute `id` in your forms param. So the `forms.id == 'myForm'` will return `false`.